# Extract type from callback argument

Tags: typescript

Library I use has the following TS class:

```js
class Embed {
  // ...
  addEventListener(
    name: "userInterfaceStateChange",
    cb: (data: {
      hiddenElements: string[];
      isFullscreen: boolean;
      isSoftKeyboardVisible: boolean;
    }) => void
  );
  //...
}
```

How in my code I can extract the type of `data`?
So the extracted type will equal to:

```js
type CallbackParametr = {
  hiddenElements: string[];
  isFullscreen: boolean;
  isSoftKeyboardVisible: boolean;
};
```

I need to use this type in some other places in my code but I don't want to copy-paste it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Parameters` [[1]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) utility type to quickly drill into the parameters of the method then callback.

```js
class Embed {
  addEventListener(
    name: "userInterfaceStateChange",
    cb: (data: {
      hiddenElements: string[];
      isFullscreen: boolean;
      isSoftKeyboardVisible: boolean;
    }) => void
){};
};

type CB = Parameters<Embed['addEventListener']>[1];
type Data = Parameters<CB>[0];
/* 
    type Data = {
        hiddenElements: string[];
        isFullscreen: boolean;
        isSoftKeyboardVisible: boolean;
    }
*/
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiC2AjApgE2gbwFDWmVqsAbsgHYAuAMgJYTlnIBOAFDrtKWPMgFzQBEAVwhMAkhSYAzMMGQBlcmHoBhABZhSAc2T8ANG1zBEfZqiVg%202du1XUCZWCGTcKEPnUbUtAbQC6AbgN2WgAxQRAQCGBGZDI%20RAB7BKcNQOtcWjkEyXIAaWQAT0SwRlQANVpqRCd4pJTSNPYAXwBKaABeAD5oIgS7LBaMJsDhrCxyAoAHZGhlACEO6AAFEq5kekYIAB4EFFRvAHJ8QhIKGjoGRgPfTu8ARgDxqZmAEXNFlcY1je3524AGR4AegAVNAntNoG9FIsrDY7KgHE4XOQ3NAPF5NH5GhkIGEIlEYnFoIlkshUkFMtk8oViqUKhAqjUSXVyQ0sE0sCCgUA)